# WPF Grid Row Sizing issue

Tags: wpf, xaml

In a WPF project I have a Grid that has 3 rows. In each row I have a StackPanel containing a TextBlock.

When all the StackPanels are Visible I would like each StackPanel to occupy 1/3 of the Height of the Grid each. But when a single StackPanel is Collapsed then the remaining 2 StackPanels occupy 1/2 of the Height of the Grid each. And, if 2 are collapsed then the remaining one fills the whole Grid.

Below is some sample code illustrating the UI.

If I change the 3rd `RowDefinition` `Height` to `"Auto"` and set the `panel3.Visibility = "Collapsed"` then the right thing happens. But then if I change it back to 'Visible' then it doesn't work.

I can't see a way to achieve what I want.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="panel1" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Visible">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt1" Text="FIRST ROW" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="panel2" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Visible">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt2" Text="SECOND ROW" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="panel3" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Visible">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt3" Text="THIRD ROW" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Maybe use a `StackPanel` that contains the 3 stackpanels and adjust the size of the visible stackpanels when one or more stackpanels are set invisible?

Comment: Other option is to make a grid of 6 rows and use `Rowspan` to adjust the heigt of each stackpanel. If 3 visible: all stackpanels have `Rowspan=2'. If one stackpanel invisible, the other two have `Rowspan=3`. If two stackpanels invisible, the remaining stackpanel has `Rowspan=6'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try UniformGrid with one column instead of Grid:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1">
    <StackPanel x:Name="panel1" Visibility="Visible">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt1" Text="FIRST ROW" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="panel2" Visibility="Visible">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt2" Text="SECOND ROW" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="panel3" Visibility="Visible">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt3" Text="THIRD ROW" />
    </StackPanel>
</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: I think the 'Column' attribute needs to be 'Columns' however.

Answer (score 0):

When the `Visibility` of the `Grid` to `Collapsed` you can set the height of `Grid.RowDefinition` to `Auto` like following:

```
row1.Height = GridLength.Auto;
```

When the `Visibility` of the `Grid` to `Visible` you can set the height of `Grid.RowDefinition` to `1*` like following:

```
row1.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
```